# Change the value of a field in Rails Sqlite via terminal

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, terminal

How do I change the value in Rails table using terminal/command line?
For example I have a table "users" with one field admin set to "false" and I want to change it to true via terminal - as below:

```
 update users set admin = true where email = joe@example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Rails 4:

```
user = User.find_by email: "joe@example.com"
user.update!(admin: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rails c`:

```
user = User.where(email: "joe@example.com").first
user.update_coluns(admin: true)
```

OR, for example to multiples entries:

```
User.where(email: "joe@example.com").update_all(admin: true)
```